# How can i change the cursor (image) in the whole windows OS

Tags: c#, .net

I need to change the cursor in all windows, not just in the application, i have try this:

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
```

And this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor;
```

But it only changes the cursor in my application.

Any idea?

Comment: I would be pissed off to use an application that changes the behavior or rendering of my other applications. Especially without asking me first!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you have your own cursor file (.cur) to apply you could hack this.

First you will have to change thje default Arrow cursor in the Registry, then you will need to call some P-Invoke to allow the OS to update the current sytem paramerters so the cursor actually changes.

Somthing like:

```
    private void ChangeCursor(string curFile)
    {
        Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Cursors\", "Arrow", curFile);
        SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETCURSORS, 0, null, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE); 
    }

    const int SPI_SETCURSORS = 0x0057; 
    const int SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01; 
    const int SPIF_SENDCHANGE = 0x02; 

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SystemParametersInfo")]
    public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, uint? pvParam, uint fWinIni);
```

Usage:

```
 ChangeCursor(@"C:\MyCursor.cur");
```

Comment: I am getting a Marshal DirectiveException: Cannot marshal 'parameter #3': Generic types cannot be marshaled. why is this happening?

Comment: The only problem was the ? at: uint? pvParam

Comment: ahhh.. yes silly me :(, I never tested the code first, my bad.

Comment: I appreciate it very much for sharing this !! just there seems to be a typing mistake in `unint? pvParam` which should be `unint pvParam` and also replacing `null` with `0` as in `SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETCURSORS, 0, null, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);`

Answer (score 3):

## You cannot change the cursor of the entire OS without modifying the registry.

You need to modify the registry to change the cursor.

See here for a tutorial and the exact `Registry` keys you need to modify - programmatically.

http://www.thebitguru.com/articles/14-Programmatically+Changing+Windows+Mouse+Cursors

Comment: +1 this is the WTG, the API call I mention is for setting other Control Panel Mouse settings - not the icon.

Answer (score 1):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SystemParametersInfo")]
public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, ref uint pvParam, uint fWinIni);

public enum SystemParametersInfoAction : uint
    {
        SPI_GETBEEP = 0x0001,
        SPI_SETBEEP = 0x0002,
        SPI_GETMOUSE = 0x0003,
        SPI_SETMOUSE = 0x0004,
        SPI_GETBORDER = 0x0005,
        SPI_SETBORDER = 0x0006,
        SPI_GETKEYBOARDSPEED = 0x000A,
        SPI_SETKEYBOARDSPEED = 0x000B,
        SPI_LANGDRIVER = 0x000C,
        SPI_ICONHORIZONTALSPACING = 0x000D,
        SPI_GETSCREENSAVETIMEOUT = 0x000E,
        SPI_SETSCREENSAVETIMEOUT = 0x000F,
        SPI_GETSCREENSAVEACTIVE = 0x0010,
        SPI_SETSCREENSAVEACTIVE = 0x0011,
        SPI_GETGRIDGRANULARITY = 0x0012,
        SPI_SETGRIDGRANULARITY = 0x0013,
        SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x0014,
        SPI_SETDESKPATTERN = 0x0015,
        SPI_GETKEYBOARDDELAY = 0x0016,
        SPI_SETKEYBOARDDELAY = 0x0017,
        SPI_ICONVERTICALSPACING = 0x0018,
        SPI_GETICONTITLEWRAP = 0x0019,
        SPI_SETICONTITLEWRAP = 0x001A,
        SPI_GETMENUDROPALIGNMENT = 0x001B,
        SPI_SETMENUDROPALIGNMENT = 0x001C,
        SPI_SETDOUBLECLKWIDTH = 0x001D,
        SPI_SETDOUBLECLKHEIGHT = 0x001E,
        SPI_GETICONTITLELOGFONT = 0x001F,
        SPI_SETDOUBLECLICKTIME = 0x0020,
        SPI_SETMOUSEBUTTONSWAP = 0x0021,
        SPI_SETICONTITLELOGFONT = 0x0022,
        SPI_GETFASTTASKSWITCH = 0x0023,
        SPI_SETFASTTASKSWITCH = 0x0024,
        SPI_SETDRAGFULLWINDOWS = 0x0025,
        SPI_GETDRAGFULLWINDOWS = 0x0026,
        SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS = 0x0029,
        SPI_SETNONCLIENTMETRICS = 0x002A,
        SPI_GETMINIMIZEDMETRICS = 0x002B,
        SPI_SETMINIMIZEDMETRICS = 0x002C,
        SPI_GETICONMETRICS = 0x002D,
        SPI_SETICONMETRICS = 0x002E,
        SPI_SETWORKAREA = 0x002F,
        SPI_GETWORKAREA = 0x0030,
        SPI_SETPENWINDOWS = 0x0031,
        SPI_GETHIGHCONTRAST = 0x0042,
        SPI_SETHIGHCONTRAST = 0x0043,
        SPI_GETKEYBOARDPREF = 0x0044,
        SPI_SETKEYBOARDPREF = 0x0045,
        SPI_GETSCREENREADER = 0x0046,
        SPI_SETSCREENREADER = 0x0047,
        SPI_GETANIMATION = 0x0048,
        SPI_SETANIMATION = 0x0049,
        SPI_GETFONTSMOOTHING = 0x004A,
        SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHING = 0x004B,
        SPI_SETDRAGWIDTH = 0x004C,
        SPI_SETDRAGHEIGHT = 0x004D,
        SPI_SETHANDHELD = 0x004E,
        SPI_GETLOWPOWERTIMEOUT = 0x004F,
        SPI_GETPOWEROFFTIMEOUT = 0x0050,
        SPI_SETLOWPOWERTIMEOUT = 0x0051,
        SPI_SETPOWEROFFTIMEOUT = 0x0052,
        SPI_GETLOWPOWERACTIVE = 0x0053,
        SPI_GETPOWEROFFACTIVE = 0x0054,
        SPI_SETLOWPOWERACTIVE = 0x0055,
        SPI_SETPOWEROFFACTIVE = 0x0056,
        SPI_SETCURSORS = 0x0057,
        SPI_SETICONS = 0x0058,
        SPI_GETDEFAULTINPUTLANG = 0x0059,
        SPI_SETDEFAULTINPUTLANG = 0x005A,
        SPI_SETLANGTOGGLE = 0x005B,
        SPI_GETWINDOWSEXTENSION = 0x005C,
        SPI_SETMOUSETRAILS = 0x005D,
        SPI_GETMOUSETRAILS = 0x005E,
        SPI_SETSCREENSAVERRUNNING = 0x0061,
        SPI_SCREENSAVERRUNNING = SPI_SETSCREENSAVERRUNNING,
        SPI_GETFILTERKEYS = 0x0032,
        SPI_SETFILTERKEYS = 0x0033,
        SPI_GETTOGGLEKEYS = 0x0034,
        SPI_SETTOGGLEKEYS = 0x0035,
        SPI_GETMOUSEKEYS = 0x0036,
        SPI_SETMOUSEKEYS = 0x0037,
        SPI_GETSHOWSOUNDS = 0x0038,
        SPI_SETSHOWSOUNDS = 0x0039,
        SPI_GETSTICKYKEYS = 0x003A,
        SPI_SETSTICKYKEYS = 0x003B,
        SPI_GETACCESSTIMEOUT = 0x003C,
        SPI_SETACCESSTIMEOUT = 0x003D,
        SPI_GETSERIALKEYS = 0x003E,
        SPI_SETSERIALKEYS = 0x003F,
        SPI_GETSOUNDSENTRY = 0x0040,
        SPI_SETSOUNDSENTRY = 0x0041,
        SPI_GETSNAPTODEFBUTTON = 0x005F,
        SPI_SETSNAPTODEFBUTTON = 0x0060,
        SPI_GETMOUSEHOVERWIDTH = 0x0062,
        SPI_SETMOUSEHOVERWIDTH = 0x0063,
        SPI_GETMOUSEHOVERHEIGHT = 0x0064,
        SPI_SETMOUSEHOVERHEIGHT = 0x0065,
        SPI_GETMOUSEHOVERTIME = 0x0066,
        SPI_SETMOUSEHOVERTIME = 0x0067,
        SPI_GETWHEELSCROLLLINES = 0x0068,
        SPI_SETWHEELSCROLLLINES = 0x0069,
        SPI_GETMENUSHOWDELAY = 0x006A,
        SPI_SETMENUSHOWDELAY = 0x006B,
        SPI_GETWHEELSCROLLCHARS = 0x006C,
        SPI_SETWHEELSCROLLCHARS = 0x006D,
        SPI_GETSHOWIMEUI = 0x006E,
        SPI_SETSHOWIMEUI = 0x006F,
        SPI_GETMOUSESPEED = 0x0070,
        SPI_SETMOUSESPEED = 0x0071,
        SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING = 0x0072,
        SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x0073,
        SPI_GETAUDIODESCRIPTION = 0x0074,
        SPI_SETAUDIODESCRIPTION = 0x0075,
        SPI_GETSCREENSAVESECURE = 0x0076,
        SPI_SETSCREENSAVESECURE = 0x0077,
        SPI_GETHUNGAPPTIMEOUT = 0x0078,
        SPI_SETHUNGAPPTIMEOUT = 0x0079,
        SPI_GETWAITTOKILLTIMEOUT = 0x007A,
        SPI_SETWAITTOKILLTIMEOUT = 0x007B,
        SPI_GETWAITTOKILLSERVICETIMEOUT = 0x007C,
        SPI_SETWAITTOKILLSERVICETIMEOUT = 0x007D,
        SPI_GETMOUSEDOCKTHRESHOLD = 0x007E,
        SPI_SETMOUSEDOCKTHRESHOLD = 0x007F,
        SPI_GETPENDOCKTHRESHOLD = 0x0080,
        SPI_SETPENDOCKTHRESHOLD = 0x0081,
        SPI_GETWINARRANGING = 0x0082,
        SPI_SETWINARRANGING = 0x0083,
        SPI_GETMOUSEDRAGOUTTHRESHOLD = 0x0084,
        SPI_SETMOUSEDRAGOUTTHRESHOLD = 0x0085,
        SPI_GETPENDRAGOUTTHRESHOLD = 0x0086,
        SPI_SETPENDRAGOUTTHRESHOLD = 0x0087,
        SPI_GETMOUSESIDEMOVETHRESHOLD = 0x0088,
        SPI_SETMOUSESIDEMOVETHRESHOLD = 0x0089,
        SPI_GETPENSIDEMOVETHRESHOLD = 0x008A,
        SPI_SETPENSIDEMOVETHRESHOLD = 0x008B,
        SPI_GETDRAGFROMMAXIMIZE = 0x008C,
        SPI_SETDRAGFROMMAXIMIZE = 0x008D,
        SPI_GETSNAPSIZING = 0x008E,
        SPI_SETSNAPSIZING = 0x008F,
        SPI_GETDOCKMOVING = 0x0090,
        SPI_SETDOCKMOVING = 0x0091,
        SPI_GETACTIVEWINDOWTRACKING = 0x1000,
        SPI_SETACTIVEWINDOWTRACKING = 0x1001,
        SPI_GETMENUANIMATION = 0x1002,
        SPI_SETMENUANIMATION = 0x1003,
        SPI_GETCOMBOBOXANIMATION = 0x1004,
        SPI_SETCOMBOBOXANIMATION = 0x1005,
        SPI_GETLISTBOXSMOOTHSCROLLING = 0x1006,
        SPI_SETLISTBOXSMOOTHSCROLLING = 0x1007,
        SPI_GETGRADIENTCAPTIONS = 0x1008,
        SPI_SETGRADIENTCAPTIONS = 0x1009,
        SPI_GETKEYBOARDCUES = 0x100A,
        SPI_SETKEYBOARDCUES = 0x100B,
        SPI_GETMENUUNDERLINES = SPI_GETKEYBOARDCUES,
        SPI_SETMENUUNDERLINES = SPI_SETKEYBOARDCUES,
        SPI_GETACTIVEWNDTRKZORDER = 0x100C,
        SPI_SETACTIVEWNDTRKZORDER = 0x100D,
        SPI_GETHOTTRACKING = 0x100E,
        SPI_SETHOTTRACKING = 0x100F,
        SPI_GETMENUFADE = 0x1012,
        SPI_SETMENUFADE = 0x1013,
        SPI_GETSELECTIONFADE = 0x1014,
        SPI_SETSELECTIONFADE = 0x1015,
        SPI_GETTOOLTIPANIMATION = 0x1016,
        SPI_SETTOOLTIPANIMATION = 0x1017,
        SPI_GETTOOLTIPFADE = 0x1018,
        SPI_SETTOOLTIPFADE = 0x1019,
        SPI_GETCURSORSHADOW = 0x101A,
        SPI_SETCURSORSHADOW = 0x101B,
        SPI_GETMOUSESONAR = 0x101C,
        SPI_SETMOUSESONAR = 0x101D,
        SPI_GETMOUSECLICKLOCK = 0x101E,
        SPI_SETMOUSECLICKLOCK = 0x101F,
        SPI_GETMOUSEVANISH = 0x1020,
        SPI_SETMOUSEVANISH = 0x1021,
        SPI_GETFLATMENU = 0x1022,
        SPI_SETFLATMENU = 0x1023,
        SPI_GETDROPSHADOW = 0x1024,
        SPI_SETDROPSHADOW = 0x1025,
        SPI_GETBLOCKSENDINPUTRESETS = 0x1026,
        SPI_SETBLOCKSENDINPUTRESETS = 0x1027,
        SPI_GETUIEFFECTS = 0x103E,
        SPI_SETUIEFFECTS = 0x103F,
        SPI_GETDISABLEOVERLAPPEDCONTENT = 0x1040,
        SPI_SETDISABLEOVERLAPPEDCONTENT = 0x1041,
        SPI_GETCLIENTAREAANIMATION = 0x1042,
        SPI_SETCLIENTAREAANIMATION = 0x1043,
        SPI_GETCLEARTYPE = 0x1048,
        SPI_SETCLEARTYPE = 0x1049,
        SPI_GETSPEECHRECOGNITION = 0x104A,
        SPI_SETSPEECHRECOGNITION = 0x104B,
        SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT = 0x2000,
        SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT = 0x2001,
        SPI_GETACTIVEWNDTRKTIMEOUT = 0x2002,
        SPI_SETACTIVEWNDTRKTIMEOUT = 0x2003,
        SPI_GETFOREGROUNDFLASHCOUNT = 0x2004,
        SPI_SETFOREGROUNDFLASHCOUNT = 0x2005,
        SPI_GETCARETWIDTH = 0x2006,
        SPI_SETCARETWIDTH = 0x2007,
        SPI_GETMOUSECLICKLOCKTIME = 0x2008,
        SPI_SETMOUSECLICKLOCKTIME = 0x2009,
        SPI_GETFONTSMOOTHINGTYPE = 0x200A,
        SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHINGTYPE = 0x200B,
        SPI_GETFONTSMOOTHINGCONTRAST = 0x200C,
        SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHINGCONTRAST = 0x200D,
        SPI_GETFOCUSBORDERWIDTH = 0x200E,
        SPI_SETFOCUSBORDERWIDTH = 0x200F,
        SPI_GETFOCUSBORDERHEIGHT = 0x2010,
        SPI_SETFOCUSBORDERHEIGHT = 0x2011,
        SPI_GETFONTSMOOTHINGORIENTATION = 0x2012,
        SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHINGORIENTATION = 0x2013,
        SPI_GETMINIMUMHITRADIUS = 0x2014,
        SPI_SETMINIMUMHITRADIUS = 0x2015,
        SPI_GETMESSAGEDURATION = 0x2016,
        SPI_SETMESSAGEDURATION = 0x2017,
    }
```

Comment: so what does that do ?

Comment: I am trying to change my mouse cursor to Cursors.Cross for hours and asked questions in this site to no avail. How can I use your solution to achieve that ?

Comment: Use ss_ddam213's answer, if you have problems getting it to work, start a new question showing what you tried, what results you get vs what you expect and ref this q/a. Good luck!