# How can I change mouse scheme using C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mouse

I need change programmatically parameter that I highlighted on the screenshot.
[image]

I think this must be an API function, but my search by internet wasn't successful.

Comment: Only in your program or in all windows?

Comment: I need change it in all windows

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016414/how-can-i-change-the-cursor-image-in-the-whole-windows-os.  If my understand is right that cursor=scheme

Comment: Thanks very much. I think that is what I searched. I'll comment result  later.

Comment: Poomrokc The 3years, +1. I did what me was need. Thanks one more times.

Comment: No problem. Congratulations! This is a nice start.

Answer (score 0):

In the Name of God, the Compassionate, the Merciful

Hello Ankur

Method is in two stages. First get properties of wanted Scheme by selecting in "Mouse Properties" window and save them and second set them. Below codes of both:

Get properties code:

```
    private void buttonGetCursorsValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegistryKey NewKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\\Cursors", true);

        for (int j = 0, loopTo = NewKey.ValueCount - 1; j <= loopTo; j++)
            Debug.WriteLine("j = " + j + ", " + NewKey.GetValue(NewKey.GetValueNames()[j]));
    }
```

Result of first stage is:

> j = 0, C:\Windows\cursors\aero_arrow.cur
>
> j = 1, C:\Windows\cursors\aero_helpsel.cur
>
> j = 2, C:\Windows\cursors\aero_link.cur
>
> j = 3, C:\Windows\cursors\aero_working.ani
>
> j = 4, C:\Windows\cursors\aero_busy.ani
>
> j = 5, C:\Windows\cursors\aero_pen.cur
>
> j = 6, C:\Windows\cursors\aero_unavail.cur
>
> j = 7, C:\Windows\cursors\aero_ns.cur
>
> j = 8, C:\Windows\cursors\aero_ew.cur
>
> j = 9, C:\Windows\cursors\aero_nwse.cur
>
> j = 10, C:\Windows\cursors\aero_nesw.cur
>
> j = 11, C:\Windows\cursors\aero_move.cur
>
> j = 12, C:\Windows\cursors\aero_up.cur
>
> j = 13, Windows Aero
>
> j = 14, 2
>
> j = 15,
>
> j = 16,

But in item 13 expression below should be added:

" (system scheme)"

i.e. expression **"Windows Aero"** should be changed to **"Windows Aero (system scheme)"**.

Set properties code:

```
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)] private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL", EntryPoint = "GetForegroundWindow")] private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)] private static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hwnd);
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)] static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowThreadProcessId")] private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId([In()] IntPtr hWnd, ref int lpdwProcessId);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowTextW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)] private static extern int GetWindowTextW(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int maxLength);

    private void buttonSetCursorsValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegistryKey NewKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\\Cursors", true);

        NewKey.SetValue(NewKey.GetValueNames()[0], @"C:\Windows\cursors\aero_arrow.cur");
        NewKey.SetValue(NewKey.GetValueNames()[1], @"C:\Windows\cursors\aero_helpsel.cur");
        NewKey.SetValue(NewKey.GetValueNames()[2], @"C:\Windows\cursors\aero_link.cur");
        NewKey.SetValue(NewKey.GetValueNames()[3], @"C:\Windows\cursors\aero_working.ani");
        NewKey.SetValue(NewKey.GetValueNames()[4], @"C:\Windows\cursors\aero_busy.ani");
        NewKey.SetValue(NewKey.GetValueNames()[5], @"C:\Windows\cursors\aero_pen.cur");
        NewKey.SetValue(NewKey.GetValueNames()[6], @"C:\Windows\cursors\aero_unavail.cur");
        NewKey.SetValue(NewKey.GetValueNames()[7], @"C:\Windows\cursors\aero_ns.cur");
        NewKey.SetValue(NewKey.GetValueNames()[8], @"C:\Windows\cursors\aero_ew.cur");
        NewKey.SetValue(NewKey.GetValueNames()[9], @"C:\Windows\cursors\aero_nwse.cur");
        NewKey.SetValue(NewKey.GetValueNames()[10], @"C:\Windows\cursors\aero_nesw.cur");
        NewKey.SetValue(NewKey.GetValueNames()[11], @"C:\Windows\cursors\aero_move.cur");
        NewKey.SetValue(NewKey.GetValueNames()[12], @"C:\Windows\cursors\aero_up.cur");
        NewKey.SetValue(NewKey.GetValueNames()[13], "Windows Aero (system scheme)");
        NewKey.SetValue(NewKey.GetValueNames()[14], "2");
        NewKey.SetValue(NewKey.GetValueNames()[15], "");
        NewKey.SetValue(NewKey.GetValueNames()[16], "");

        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("Control.exe") {Arguments = "Mouse"};
        Process.Start(startInfo);
        IntPtr MousePropertiesHandle = FindWindow(null, "Mouse Properties");

        while (MousePropertiesHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            if (GetForgeroundWindowInfo().Window_Title == "Mouse Properties")
            {
                SendKeys.SendWait("^{TAB}");
                SetForegroundWindow(MousePropertiesHandle);
                SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private ForegroundWindowInfo GetForgeroundWindowInfo()
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
        var FWI = new ForegroundWindowInfo();

        if (!hWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            int lgth = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
            var wTitle = new StringBuilder("", lgth + 1);
            if (lgth > 0)
                GetWindowTextW(hWnd, wTitle, wTitle.Capacity);

            int wProcID = default;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, ref wProcID);

            Process Proc = Process.GetProcessById(wProcID);
            string wFileName;

            try
            {
                wFileName = Proc.MainModule.FileName;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                wFileName = "";
            }

            FWI.Window_Handle = hWnd.ToString();
            FWI.Window_Title = wTitle.ToString();
            FWI.Process_Id = wProcID.ToString();
            FWI.Main_Module_FileName = wFileName.ToString();
        }

        return FWI;
    }
    internal partial class ForegroundWindowInfo
    {
        public string Window_Handle;
        public string Window_Title;
        public string Process_Id;
        public string Main_Module_FileName;
    }
```

Result is shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7a6fs.png).