# Change cursor while mouse dragging

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I would like to implement the next construction in .NET in a WPF application.
There is a window, and in it there is a little picture, e.g.: 16×16.
If i move the mouse above the picture, and pressed the left button (without release), the cursor will change to this picture until i release the button.
Between the press and release i would like to drag out this cursor image outside the application window.
How can i implement this feature without modifying system registry values?

---

Thanks in advance,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the Windows cursor without changing the registry. This has been discussed before: [How can i change the cursor (image) in the whole windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016414/how-can-i-change-the-cursor-image-in-the-whole-windows-os)

Comment: If you found a duplicate for this question, you should mark it as a duplicate or comment on the question, not post an answer.

Comment: @Savanna Thank you. How do I mark this as a duplicate?

Comment: To do that, use the "flag" link on the question, choose "it should be closed for another reason", followed by "duplicate of" and enter the link to the previous question.