# how can i make custom Cursor outside form?

Tags: c#

Iam using application that make a custom cursor 
i change the value of cursor Arrow in regitery to my custom curoso

but it dosnt change
Although my custom curoso show in the registry and mouse proprite 
see this image 
[image]

as you see my custom curosr show 
But didn't Apply it ?
how i applay this ?
i have this code

```
  Cursor cur = CustomCursor.FromStream(stream);
  Registry.SetValue(keyName, "Arrow", @"C:\data\custom.cur",        RegistryValueKind.String);
```

how i can make my custom cursor outside form ?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15016529/10223668) link. It can help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i change the cursor (image) in the whole windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016414/how-can-i-change-the-cursor-image-in-the-whole-windows-os)